# compatibility issue with contourArea in openCV 3

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

I am trying to do a simple area calculation of contours I get from findContours.
My openCv version is 3.1.0

My code is:

```
cc = cv2.findContours(im_bw.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.contourArea(cc[0])

error: 'C:\\builds\\master_PackSlaveAddon-win32-vc12-static\\opencv\\modules\\imgproc\\src\\shapedescr.cp...: error: (-215) npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function cv::contourArea\n'
```

Cant seem to solve it, I have a feeling its just typecasting altough I expect the findContours result to match the type of contourArea

Thanks :)

EDIT: turns out I need to take the 2nd argument of findContours

```
 im2, cc, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(im_bw.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Comment: have you checked if cc[0] is empty ?

Comment: found it after digging more, turns out I need to get the 2nd argument of findContours

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In Opencv 3 API version the `cv2.findContours()` returns 3 [objects](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html)

- image
- contours
- hierarchy

So you need to rewrite your statement as:

```
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(im_bw.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the OpenCV version, `cv2.findContours()` has varying return signatures.

In OpenCV 3.4.X, [`cv2.findContours()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a) returns 3 items

```
image, contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(image, mode, method[, contours[, hierarchy[, offset]]])
```

In OpenCV 2.X and 4.1.X, [`cv2.findContours()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0) returns 2 items

```
contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(image, mode, method[, contours[, hierarchy[, offset]]])
```

You can easily obtain the contours regardless of the version like this:

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem is caused by the different return value of cv2.findContours in different OpenCV versions.

In OpenCV 4.0.0, this error may looks like `cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\convhull.cpp:137: error: (-215:Assertion failed) total >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function 'cv::convexHull'`

You can find a detailed explanation and solutions here: [How to use `cv2.findContours` in different OpenCV versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48291581/how-to-use-cv2-findcontours-in-different-opencv-versions/48292371#48292371)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @ZdaR;
By the way,  you can do the following in OpenCV 4.1:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(im_bw.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```