# OpenCV contourArea exception

Tags: python, opencv

I am very new to opencv and i have a problem:

```
#Find contours of the filtered frame
contours, hierarchy, _= cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)   

#Draw Contours
#cv2.drawContours(frame, cnt, -1, (122,122,0), 3)
#cv2.imshow('Dilation',median)

#Find Max contour area (Assume that hand is in the frame)
max_area=100
ci=0    
for i in range(len(contours)):
    cnt=contours[i]
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if(area>max_area):
        max_area=area
        ci=i
```

i found this on the internet, some hand tracking thing but i get this exception:

```
File "C:\Users\123\Desktop\cv\track.py", line 87, 
in<module>
area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
error: C:\projects\opencv-
python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\shapedescr.cpp:320: error: (-215) npoints 
>= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function cv::contourArea
```

Could you tell me why this is happening and what's the solution?
I am using Python 2.7.13 and OpenCV version 3.3.0.
Full code here: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/midNEkMN)

Answer (score 1):

cv2.findContours returns `img, contours, hierarchy`, see the docs [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html).

Switch the order in your call and it should work.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39475125/compatibility-issue-with-contourarea-in-opencv-3) as as well.

Comment: thank you so much that worked perfectly.

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer then :)