# Hand recognition script for OpenCV+Python not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, contour

I'm trying to get the following script to work. I found it from [this](http://creat-tabu.blogspot.com/2013/08/opencv-python-hand-gesture-recognition.html) website but I keep getting the `error` :

> contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh1,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
>   ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

I have little experience in Python and *OpenCV* so if anyone here can help that would be much appreciated!
I'm running Mac OS X 10.13.4, *OpenCV* 3.4.1, Python 3.6.5
and

Here is the script I'm trying to get work :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while( cap.isOpened() ) :
    ret,img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)
    ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(blur,70,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh1,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    drawing = np.zeros(img.shape,np.uint8)

    max_area=0

    for i in range(len(contours)):
            cnt=contours[i]
            area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
            if(area>max_area):
                max_area=area
                ci=i
    cnt=contours[ci]
    hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)
    moments = cv2.moments(cnt)
    if moments['m00']!=0:
                cx = int(moments['m10']/moments['m00']) # cx = M10/M00
                cy = int(moments['m01']/moments['m00']) # cy = M01/M00

    centr=(cx,cy)       
    cv2.circle(img,centr,5,[0,0,255],2)       
    cv2.drawContours(drawing,[cnt],0,(0,255,0),2) 
    cv2.drawContours(drawing,[hull],0,(0,0,255),2) 

    cnt = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,0.01*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True),True)
    hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt,returnPoints = False)

    if(1):
               defects = cv2.convexityDefects(cnt,hull)
               mind=0
               maxd=0
               for i in range(defects.shape[0]):
                    s,e,f,d = defects[i,0]
                    start = tuple(cnt[s][0])
                    end = tuple(cnt[e][0])
                    far = tuple(cnt[f][0])
                    dist = cv2.pointPolygonTest(cnt,centr,True)
                    cv2.line(img,start,end,[0,255,0],2)

                    cv2.circle(img,far,5,[0,0,255],-1)
               print(i)
               i=0
    cv2.imshow('output',drawing)
    cv2.imshow('input',img)

    k = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if k == 27:
        break
```

Thank you so much in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function cv2.fincContours has changed since OpenCV 3.x , and back in OpenCV 4.x . Try this:

```
## Find contours
if cv2.__version__.startswith("3."):
    _, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh1,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
else:
   contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh1,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

---

Related:

1. [How to use `cv2.findContours` in different OpenCV versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48291581/opencv-with-python-video-edge-detection-typeerror/48292371#48292371)

Comment: ty so much! this fixed it but then i get another error: 'line 41, in <module>
    for i in range(defects.shape[0]):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape''

Comment: @Yian Then you should `check len(defeacts) > 0`

Comment: I tried that now but I get `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()` (thank you so much btw)