# How opencv 4.x API is different from previous version?

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11

I noted that opencv 4 is released and one difference is that API changed to be c++11 compliant.

What this really means?

How should I change my codes to be compatible with this version?

Comment: Good, but probably very broad question.  Not sure on the C++ side, but there are definitely some API changes in the Python wrappers. One thing that immediately comes to mind is `findContours` going back to returning a pair (like in 2.x sans the modification of the input image) as opposed to the triple in 3.x.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the most different is, the `OpenCV 4.0` use more C++11 features. Now `cv::String == std::string` and `cv::Ptr` is a thin wrapper on top of `std::shared_ptr`.

The Opencv 4.0 remove folder `include/opencv` and only keep `include/opencv2`. A lot of C API from OpenCV 1.x has been removed. The affected modules are `objdetect, photo, video, videoio, imgcodecs, calib3d`. The old macro defination or unnamed enum is not suggested, use named enum insted.

```
//! include/opencv2/imgcodes.hpp
namespace cv
{

//! @addtogroup imgcodecs
//! @{

//! Imread flags
enum ImreadModes {
       IMREAD_UNCHANGED            = -1, //!< If set, return the loaded image as is (with alpha channel, otherwise it gets cropped).
       IMREAD_GRAYSCALE            = 0,  //!< If set, always convert image to the single channel grayscale image (codec internal conversion).
       IMREAD_COLOR                = 1,  //!< If set, always convert image to the 3 channel BGR color image.
       IMREAD_ANYDEPTH             = 2,  //!< If set, return 16-bit/32-bit image when the input has the corresponding depth, otherwise convert it to 8-bit.
       IMREAD_ANYCOLOR             = 4,  //!< If set, the image is read in any possible color format.
       IMREAD_LOAD_GDAL            = 8,  //!< If set, use the gdal driver for loading the image.
       IMREAD_REDUCED_GRAYSCALE_2  = 16, //!< If set, always convert image to the single channel grayscale image and the image size reduced 1/2.
       IMREAD_REDUCED_COLOR_2      = 17, //!< If set, always convert image to the 3 channel BGR color image and the image size reduced 1/2.
       IMREAD_REDUCED_GRAYSCALE_4  = 32, //!< If set, always convert image to the single channel grayscale image and the image size reduced 1/4.
       IMREAD_REDUCED_COLOR_4      = 33, //!< If set, always convert image to the 3 channel BGR color image and the image size reduced 1/4.
       IMREAD_REDUCED_GRAYSCALE_8  = 64, //!< If set, always convert image to the single channel grayscale image and the image size reduced 1/8.
       IMREAD_REDUCED_COLOR_8      = 65, //!< If set, always convert image to the 3 channel BGR color image and the image size reduced 1/8.
       IMREAD_IGNORE_ORIENTATION   = 128 //!< If set, do not rotate the image according to EXIF's orientation flag.
     };

    // ...
}
```

Such as, when read image, it should be something like this:

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("test.png", cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
```

---

Except the new featues, the most C++ APIs keep the same. While the biggest different I found is `cv2.findContours` (in `Python OpenCV`):

In OpenCV 3.4:

```
findContours(image, mode, method[, contours[, hierarchy[, offset]]]) -> image, contours, hierarchy
```

[image]

In OpenCV 4.0:

```
findContours(image, mode, method[, contours[, hierarchy[, offset]]]) -> contours, hierarchy
```

[image]

An alternative to work with 2.x 、3.x、4.x is:

```
cnts, hiers = cv2.findContours(...)[-2:]
```

---

Some links:

1. [OpenCV Release](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases)
2. [OpenCV ChangeLog](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/ChangeLog)
3. [OpenCV Introduction](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d1/dfb/intro.html)
4. [OpenCV Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/index.html)
5. [How to use `cv2.findContours` in different OpenCV versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48291581/how-to-use-cv2-findcontours-in-different-opencv-versions/48292371#48292371)
6. [OpenCV on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv)

---

Comment: An interesting question: Why they did not use class enum and used enum? I think in C++11, the preference is class enum?

Comment: Maybe they just use historical writing? Actually I think  `enum class` or `enum struct` maybe better, because they are scopped. But as the code base is so large, there exist so many code that use unscoped one. If change `enum` to `enum class`, the existing code using `cv::IMREAD_COLOR` will  compile failed, unless modified to `cv::ImreadModes::IMREAD_COLOR`. And there're still many bugs related to `enum` changing when wrapping the  `C++ OpenCV API` into `Python|Java|C#`.   So they just keep? I'm not really sure.

Comment: And here is [a `enum struct` issue on github in Java binding](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/13471)

Answer (score 8):

According to [OpenCV 4.0.0](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/ChangeLog#version400), you don't have to make any significant modifications (most likely any at all) to your source codes, unless you are using some C API which has been removed.

As already stated

> OpenCV is now C++11 library and **requires** C++11-compliant compiler

To use `c++11`, clang version 3.3 and higher is required with flag `-std=c++11`. Same for g++ 4.3 and higher.

It allows them to use `std::string` instead of `cv::String`, and other c++11 features. But don't worry, `cv::String` will still work, but is now allias for `std::string`. Similliar for smart pointers, etc.

Comment: Just curious, have you tried upgrading any sort of production code to 4.x? With this you're tempting me to spend the holidays building new deps and porting the code :D

Comment: Actually I have re-written few modules from C API to C++. It is not as hard as it might seem -- almost all C functions e.g. `cvCvtColor` have their equivalents in C++ `cv::cvtColor` (with same functionality). Also there is support for conversion from old-style C types to C++ types, as you can see e.g. [here](https://physics.nyu.edu/grierlab/manuals/opencv/classcv_1_1Mat.html#ac54e1c5025e8afd7641fd2a37a3deef7). Hopefully you won't spend holidays that way :D

Comment: @FilipKočica The official OpenCV documentation is [here](https://docs.opencv.org/) by the way.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most vital impact is you need to use a c++11 compiler.

Also, it may not change the interface but allow them to make use of the updated Language changes, such as smart pointers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The above comment "According to OpenCV 4.0.0, you don't have to make any significant modifications (most likely any at all) to your source codes, unless you are using some C API which has been removed." appears to be far from true.

I and my partner developed a package for a collaborator. We used v 3.4 (C++140 ; the collaborator has installed v 4.5. Now we are finding our code can't be compiled on their system because of numerous symbol name changes. Examples: CV_THRESH_TOZERO, CV_GRAYTORGB.

We do know how to solve the problem (short of rewriting our software) which involves a pile of #ifdefs. However this is not the usual meaning of "backward compatible". And it should not have been necessary: the opencv people should have kept the old definitions as well as the new ones.