# Thinness ratio calculation - wrong results

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, optimization, geometry

I have a problem with calculating thinness ratio. It gives me value of 0.9 instead of 1.

Thinness ratio is given as a

```
(4 * pi * area) / (perimeter * perimeter)
```

For circle, the above equation, should give a result 1.0.

[image: image of circle]

```
import cv2
import math
image = cv2.imread("circle.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cnt = cv2.findContours(gray.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[1]

for c in cnt:
            # compute the area of the contour along with the bounding box
            # to compute the aspect ratio
            area = cv2.contourArea(c)
            perimeter = cv2.arcLength(c,True)
ti= (4*area*math.pi)/(perimeter**2)
print(ti)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
Your posted code includes graphic input, two function calls, and a calculation.  Where in all of that has the discrepancy occurred?

Comment: Did you try `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE`?

Comment: The `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE` function gives me the same results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is due to the contour finding code returning an exact outline which, maybe due to aliasing errors, is actually longer than it should be.  If I smooth the resulting contour I get the "right" value of ~1.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import splprep, splev

image = cv2.imread("circle.png", 0)
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 127, 255, 0)

# remove extra dimensions here to simplify later code
[contour], hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)
contour = contour[:,0,:]

# smooth contour
tck, u = splprep(contour.T, u=None, s=30, per=1)
u_new = np.linspace(u.min(), u.max(), 50)
new_cont = np.column_stack(splev(u_new, tck, der=0))

# change types to stop cv2 complaining
new_cont = new_cont.astype(np.float32)

# calculate as before
area = cv2.contourArea(new_cont)
circum = cv2.arcLength(new_cont, True)

(4 * pi * area) / (circum**2)
```

giving me 0.9986, which is OK for me.  Note that if you're running OpenCV version 3 you'll need to change the `findContours` line as it [returns a triple instead of a pair of values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53906178/1358308).

I've borrowed the bspline smoothing code from [here](https://agniva.me/scipy/2016/10/25/contour-smoothing.html) which seems to have in turn been borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31466013/1358308).  You can play with the various smoothing factors (try taking `s` down to 1), and where to sample it (change the last parameter to `linspace`).

Comment: Thank you Sam! I was also aware about aliasing errors, but I didn't think it was the reason. The line 9 should be changed to `_, [contour], hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)` as stated here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25504964/opencv-python-valueerror-too-many-values-to-unpack). I need to test the code with my other cases today, and if it works I will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: huh, you must be running quite an old version, it apparently changed [a year ago](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/commit/8eb987e39351fa1e28c1d2919c86cc6483b6b414).  might be worth updating if you can, there will presumably be lots of other bug fixes as well

Comment: You are right, thanks again! I checked and I use the one, which comes with anaconda package. It is pretty old then.