# How could I count the number of the light small clusters in a feature map

Tags: algorithm, opencv, computer-vision, heatmap, counting

Suppose I have a heat map like this:

[image]

The value of the  pixels on the heat map ranges from 0-1. The closer the value to 0 the darker the pixel is. There are six write clusters on it, as shown in the picture. Is there any method  for me to know how many light clusters are there in the heatmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source => Detection

[image]
[image]

---

My method is:  Gray => Threshold => FindContours (filter by area if necessary)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2019/03/01
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("featmap.png")

# Gray => Threshold => FindContours (filter by area if necessary)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blured = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 3)
th, threshed = cv2.threshold(blured, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU|cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cnts = cv2.findContours(threshed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[-2]

print("nums: {}".format(len(cnts)))

# draw on the original
cv2.drawContours(img, cnts, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.imwrite("dst.png", img)
```

Be carefully when using `findContours`: [How to use `cv2.findContours` in different OpenCV versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48291581/how-to-use-cv2-findcontours-in-different-opencv-versions/48292371#48292371)

Answer (score 0):

You can apply [cvThreshold](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html) operation to make B/W image.

Then filter small defects with [opening morhological operation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html)

Now find [connected components](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gac2718a64ade63475425558aa669a943a) and get number of them.