# Crop subimage from image with Edge Detection

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

So basically I have an image with whitespace and a text above.
The output should be only the picture. Without the text and the whitespaces. The best example would probably be a meme:

[image: like this]

I believe I would have to get the corner coordinates and then use something like pillow's `Image.crop(corner_coordinates)`.

How could I implement this?

Edit: So I tried a little bit. I used the Canny Edge Detection Algorithm (opencv). Im now getting the desired edges bit also the edges from the text. Would be nice if someone could help me:)

Comment: Try OpenCV `findContours()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find bounding rectangle of the largest contour that is not white.

I suggest using the following stages:

- Convert image from BGR to Gray.
- Convert from gray to to binary image.
  Use automatic threshold (use `cv2.THRESH_OTSU` flag) and invert polarity.
  The result is white color where original image is dark, and black where image is bright.
- Find contours using `cv2.findContours()` (as Mark Setchell commented).
  Finding the outer contour is simpler solution than detecting the edges.
- Find the bounding rectangle of the contour with the maximum area.
- Crop the bounding rectangle from the input image.
  I used NumPy array slicing instead of using pillow.

Here is the code:

```
import cv2

# Read input image
img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')

# Convert from BGR to Gray.
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Convert to binary image using automatic threshold and invert polarity
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Find contours on thresh
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[-2]  # Use index [-2] to be compatible to OpenCV 3 and 4

# Get contour with maximum area
c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)

# Crop the bounding rectangle (use .copy to get a copy instead of slice).
crop = img[y:y+h, x:x+w, :].copy()


# Draw red rectangle for testing
cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), thickness = 2)

# Show result
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('crop', crop)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Result:

`crop`:
[image]

`img`:
[image]

`thresh`:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Why would I need to use index -2? Why is that necessary in opencv3/4?

Comment: See: [How to use `cv2.findContours` in different OpenCV versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48291581/how-to-use-cv2-findcontours-in-different-opencv-versions/48292371#48292371).