# opencv ValueError in find contour function - other solutions didn't work

Tags: python, opencv

I've been using a little Python program from [here](https://github.com/gregtinkers/carspeed.py).
This has been working great until recently I had to wipe and reinstall my RaspberryPi, and now after reinstalling everything including Python and opencv, I seem to have some backward compatibility issue, the following line in the code fails and throwing the error below:

#### Code

```
thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=2)
(_, cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

This to dilate the thresholded image to fill in any holes, then find contours on thresholded image

#### Error

```
File "/home/pi/carspeed/carspeed.py", line 228, in <module>
    (_, cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

I tried different things I found online, including changing the lines to this, but to no avail

```
(_, cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

(The answer I found online is:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

But since the original code is setting the `(_, cnts, _)` variable, I thought I had no choice and used the same.)

Comment: Check the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48292371/4926757). You may also use imutils: `cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cv.findContours(...))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved -
The new code for the latest version of opencv should like this:

```
(cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The repository you're addressing is using OpenCV 3.x. However You're using OpenCV 4.x. Output of findContours is changed in OpenCV 4

***What variable is missing in OpenCV4?***

[As stated in the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.17/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0), OpenCV3's findContours method used to return the source image itself too, which also is unnecessary in your case. If you want to use source image again, you can just create a new variable and call `copy = img.copy`.

[Example findContours usage for OpenCV3.x](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/d0d/tutorial_find_contours.html)

[Example findContours usage for OpenCV4.x](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/df/d0d/tutorial_find_contours.html)